# Trying to create a curved list in android

Tags: android

I am trying to create an android app. I have two lists, each displaying different things, and I want each list to be almost a half circle around a clock.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/642577/Half-circle-listview)  for your question how to make a half circular listview

Comment: Holy crap that was fast and thats amazing!! Thank you so much! I'll be sure to check the link out in more detail tomorrow.